# Binary search using recursion taking only the searched value in parameter

Tags: java, recursion

I actually need to solve the problem by taking only searched item in the paramerised constructor. How do I do it? I am stuck with the program!

I could do it well with the middle element, but when I tried for the other element other than mid, It showed me stack overflow error.

```
public static int binary_search(int v)
{
    l=0;
    u=n-1;
    int mid = (l+u)/2;
    if(A[mid]==v)
        return 1;
    else if(v<A[mid])
    {
        binary_search(v);
        mid = mid-1;
    }
    else if(v>A[mid])
    {
        binary_search(v);
        mid = mid+1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

It went well with the middle element but with others, there's no solution.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on how to debug your code

Comment: Note that your code never can report that the element is not found. You check `A[mid]` for 3 conditions that exhaust all the possibilities, and unless you find the element, you keep searching recursively. Check if the range width becomes < 2 and stop then. Also, as @user7 notes below, you never actually update `u` and `l`.

Comment: And please post a [mcve]. Your current code example has a compiler error because it is missing a class. Also, you mention a "constructor" in your question but don't show it.

Comment: What all did you try before posting here? Did you try debugging?

Comment: Is there any prohibition to writing a recursive private method that takes more arguments, and gets invoked behind the scenes by the public-facing method with the one argument?  This approach has the added advantage that you can do argument checking in the front end, but don't need to keep redoing checks with each recursive call.

Comment: Yes. Kinda. Actually, I need to use only one argument in the function statement. Can you help me out if you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the updated `l` and `u` as parameters to the recursive method. What you are doing is assigning the same values to `l`(=0) and `u`(=n-1) in each call. In other words, each recursive call does not solve a *smaller* problem. It is the *same* problem and hence it results in a StackOverflow.

Here's a pseudocode

```
int binarySearch(int v, int l, int u) {
    if (l <= u) {
       find mid
       is the element at mid:
           return 1;// Can be 'mid' to return the index at which it was found.
       should we go left:
           return binarySearch(v, l, mid - 1);
       should we go right:
           return binarySearch(v, mid + 1, u);
    } 
    return -1; //Not found
}
```

Things to note:

1. The base condition (`l <= u`). This will enable us to detect missing element condition and terminate the recursion.
2. The `return` keyword in each recursive call without which you will always return -1.

**UPDATE:**

If you have `l` and `u` declared static, you need to update them before making the recursive call.

```
int binarySearch(int v) {
    if (l <= u) {
       find mid
       is the element at mid:
           return 1;// Can be 'mid' to return the index at which it was found.
       should we go left:
           u = mid - 1
           return binarySearch(v);
       should we go right: 
           l = mid + 1
           return binarySearch(v);
    } 
    return -1; //Not found
}
```

Note: You have to set `l = 0` and `u = n - 1` before calling this method.

Comment: I could do this if my question was about int binary_search(int, int, int). But my problem is I am asked to do it in int binary_search(int)

Comment: Then either you need to do it iteratively or make the `l` and `u` global (static) variables (not clean)

Comment: I have already declared them static. I am just giving values inside the function block. And no, I don't have the option to do it iteratively

Comment: See my **UPDATE**

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your update. But since you have just put one parameter in function and returning three parameters, may I know if your code works?

Comment: Missed to modify the method call approproiately. Check now.

Comment: I already tried. It showed me an error that the function is in (int) and you are returning (int, int, int)

Comment: I don't get what your error is. In Java, you cannot return more than one value from a function.

Comment: See, the main function is in format - int binary_search(int). And we are returning (int, int, int) So, we can't return like that.

Comment: Didn't save the code after edit. Fixed it now. *Correction:* We are not returning 3 values. Those are 3 values passed as parameter. Anyway, fixed it now

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped. And thank you for your precious time!!